# Spring Boot Hibernate update from 5.0 to 5.2 test now throws SQL Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I got a Spring Boot Project and I have to update the Hibernate Version.
Old version:

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.0.12.Final')
```

new Version:

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.2.3.Final')
```

Now I get the following exception:

```
Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "2018-11-13 10:28:26.053" SQL statement:
update myColumn set started_by=null, started_expires=null where 
started_expires<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [90003-197]
```

The query is this:

```
@Repository
public interface StartedRepository extends CrudRepository<StartedEntity, String> {

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Started R SET R.startedBy = null, R.startedExpires = null WHERE R.startedExpires < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ")
int removeAllStarted();
```

Does anyone know that the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the [migration guide for version 5.2](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2/migration-guide.adoc) and for [version 5.1](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.1/migration/) ?

Comment: Now I have and I found my problem. Hibernate-java8 is now merged into hiberate-core. Used hibernate and now it works! Thank you